# Adding an item to ItemControl which is not from binding Items Source

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on generating a list of check boxes with the first check box to be "SelectAll". SelectAll checkbox will check or uncheck all the check box in the list. However my check list is binding to a data source. Right now I want to put all check box including selectAll check box in the same wrappanel so that they can be wrapped together at the end of the panel.

```
            <ContentControl Name="FilterContent">
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <CheckBox Name="SelectedAll" MinWidth="100" Margin="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectAll, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=SelectAllText}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=OnClickCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CheckBox>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StandardItems}"
                            Margin="2,5,2,-1"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Name="ItemsPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="ItemCheckBox" 
                                    MinWidth="100" Margin="2"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Content="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ContentControl>
```

This piece of code does not allow me to do that, the result UI only have the items inside item control wrapped in the second line but not consider all check box in the same wrappanel. I need help on adding "SelectAll" check box to the wrappanel that is used by itemscontrol.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When loading the control I would add an empty StandardItem in the StandardItems list which will mean "select all". When I process the checkbox click event, I check if the item is an empty item and I use this as a call to "select all"

Comment: I fixed this problem by adding "SelectAll" to my binding ItemList, in the view mode for each item in the list I added a OnCheck/OnUncheck command. But for SelectAll I attached a different Command to OnCheck/OnUncheck action